# How to swing an Object by linear interpolation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, unity3d-2dtools

i trying  to swing an object by using Linear interpolation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use RotateAround function of transform:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        transform.RotateAround(transform.position, Vector3.up, alpha);
    }
}
```

where alpha is the angle you wish to rotate, and you need update this to make smooth rotations.

[image]